# Serialize Java Thrift Object to JSON while keeping enum names

Tags: java, json, serialization, thrift

My java project uses the Apache Thrift framework and it has a similar Thrift object structure as the following:

```
struct MyStruct {
  1: required string something;
  2: optional OptionEnum option;
}
enum OptionEnum {
  VALUE_A = 0,
  VALUE_B = 1
}
```

So when my project compiles it builds a Java class for this structure (ie: class MyStruct).

What I am trying to do is to serialize this into a string Json.

I've tried using TSerializer:

```java
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
return serializer.toString(instanceOfMyStruct);
```

This generates a json but loses the string name of the enum (it converts into a numeric value instead):

```
{
  something: 'value',
  option: 1
}
```

Is there a way to keep the enum name (I mean option being `VALUE_B` instead of `1` in the above example) ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the conversion is baked into the code parts generated by the Thrift compiler. The [protocol level](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.java) classes only know about a few very basic data types - when the data reach that level it is already too late.

So, unless you want to fork and implement your own (incompatible) version of the code generator, I'm afraid there is no way.

PS: I might add that the main purpose driving the design is efficiency, not human readibility.

Comment: I understand and your explanation makes sense.

The funny thing is that our endpoints uses JAX-RS, ex:
```
  @POST
  @Path("/apiCall")
  @Produces({
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
  })
  @Consumes({
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
  })
  public ThriftResponse apiCall()
```

And it is able to output a full json when the endpoint is called (with enums string and all).

So my guess is that there would be a way to do the same thing: serialize the `ThriftResponse` into a string.